# Trying to get 1 match per day SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Okay very new to SQL Server, so please be patient.

I'm trying to find the start time for everyday to generate an automated report for work for the last 30 days. I've managed to get some information working but I'm struggling with what I thought would be a basic one.

So some basic back ground. when we are in production the step number is 30. that would be enough if production ran smoothly every day. What I'm trying to do is find the time we go into step 30 and vats produced = 1

I thought I had it with this:

```
use Runtime

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -30, @enddate)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT 
    a.TagName, a.DateTime, a.Value, 
    b.tagname, b.value, b.DateTime, a.StartDateTime
FROM
    History A, History B
WHERE
    a.tagname = ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo') 
    AND b.tagname = ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced')
    AND a.Value = '30' 
    AND b.value = '1'
    AND a.DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND b.DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

However this returns this result

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgqWi.png)

I seem to get the start time for going into step 30  for each of the 30 days. but 30 rows for each day with datetime for the 1st vat for each of the last 30.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm thinking I need a join but both are stored in the same table

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the expected output?  Are a.DateTime and a.StartDateTime supposed to be the same?

Comment: You need sample data and desired results.

Comment: Looks like you might need another join field ... to avoid a cross join of the two tables.  Or possibly change to a union of two select statements ...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Mark M. Its from a historian database. Id bastardised the query from the historian client. Ideally i would be wanting 1 row a day showing the time vat 1 was selected to fill (vats produced) and the actual time product is started be be sent to it the step 30.  Its trying to get the start time thats proving to he the pain. A.datetime a.startdatetime. Have i make this as simple a screw up as this.‍♂️

Comment: Scott / Marc s. I was googling how to join the 2 statements.   All the data looks be be stored in a single table from al the sensors.    Looks like i need to do alot more reading. And get a proper offline copy of the DB to play about with.

Comment: Rare Crew.  Thanks. On holiday now for a weel but will try it once i get back.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer would depend on knowing the whole problem but reading from the question I would say that this could work.

```js
DECLARE @History TABLE (TagName VARCHAR(MAX), [DateTime] DATETIME, Value INT)

-- on 24th the 30 is reached at 10 am (10:00), Vats value 1 reached at 11 am (11:00)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200624 09:00', 1)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200624 10:00', 30)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200624 11:00', 40)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200624 12:00', 50)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200624 00:00', 0)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200624 10:00', 0)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200624 11:00', 1)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200624 12:00', 1)

-- on 25th the 30 is reached at 1 pm (13:00); Vats value 1 reached at 2 pm (14:00)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 00:00', 1)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 10:00', 4)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 11:00', 6)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 12:00', 28)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 13:00', 30)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Prod_StepNo', '20200625 15:00', 30)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200625 00:00', 0)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200625 10:00', 0)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200625 11:00', 0)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200625 14:00', 1)
INSERT INTO @History VALUES ('H20W01_Par_VatsProduced', '20200625 15:00', 1)

-- create a help table of last 10 days
DECLARE @Pivot DATETIME = DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
DECLARE @Days TABLE (Day DATETIME)
WHILE (@Pivot < GETDATE()) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Days VALUES (@Pivot)
    SET @Pivot = DATEADD(day, 1, @Pivot)
END

SELECT
    D.Day,
    MIN(HA.DateTime) AS ProductionStepReachedOn,
    MIN(HB.DateTime) AS VatsReachedOn
FROM
    @Days D
    LEFT JOIN @History HA ON 
        HA.TagName = 'H20W01_Prod_StepNo' AND
        HA.[DateTime] BETWEEN D.Day AND DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, D.Day)) AND
        HA.Value = 30
    LEFT JOIN @History HB ON 
        HB.TagName = 'H20W01_Par_VatsProduced' AND
        HB.[DateTime] BETWEEN D.Day AND DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, D.Day)) AND
        HB.Value = 1
GROUP BY
    D.Day
```